# add hyperlink in wix installer error message

Tags: wix

I'm trying to add hyperlink inside of `DisallowUpgradeErrorMessage` (from here http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html):

```
<MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="no"
    DisallowUpgradeErrorMessage='Older version of MWL installed. Please follow https://example.com/uninstall.html'
/>
```

I already try to create HTML hyperlink inside message, but got error, something like

> "invalid character inside of attribute"

**I replace <> characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`**, but it not work (shown as plain text). Is there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The default WiX dialogs do not support hyperlinks in their text so you will have to create your own custom UI rather than relying on the condition elements. You can find an example of how to do this [here](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/).

However, for the case you have mentioned you can have WiX automatically uninstall the previous version of your software. In cases such as this I have found the [Upgrade](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/upgrade.html) element to be more useful than MajorUpgrade, it allows for granular control of conditions and actions. You can view an example of using the Upgrade element as well as forcibly removing existing products [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/alexshev/2008/02/15/from-msi-to-wix-part-8-major-upgrade/).